# Android How to draw a polyline with missing coordinates?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a json file with coordinates and putting them in LatLng array. Some coordinates are missing because device is only sending coordinates if it's turned on. So when you turn off device and put it some where else polyline goes through whole map to another point and connect it. I need to somehow split polyline if the distance between two points gets too big. Drawing many polylines for each connecting point is not an option, because there can be 500000 points.

Can not post images here because I don't have reputation.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yrcfy.jpg

This is how I put coordinates inside polyline options.

mapData.routeOptions here is equal to polyline options.

```
                List<LatLng> route = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    route.addAll(positions);
            double totalDistance=0;
    if (route.size() > 1) {
        mapData.color = suppliedMapData.color;
        int color = mapData.color;
        int colorAlpha = Utils.adjustAlpha(color, ROUTE_TRANSPERENCY_PERCENTAGE);
        LatLngBounds.Builder boundsBuilder = LatLngBounds.builder();
        for (LatLng position : route) {
            boundsBuilder.include(position);

        }
        mapData.routeBounds = boundsBuilder.build();
        mapData.routeOptions = new PolylineOptions().addAll(route).color(colorAlpha);
```

This is how I draw polyline.

```
            int size = sArray.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

            MapData mapData = sArray.valueAt(i);
            if (mapData.routeOptions != null) {                         
            mapData.routeOptions.width(7);
                            mPolylines.add(mMap.addPolyline(mapData.routeOptions));     

                hasPosData = true;
            }}
```

Polylines are added to mPolylines array. because there are more devices than one and all off them need to be drawn.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: code added..(comment too short)

Comment: When do you `clear()` your Map?

Comment: I clear everything that is on the map after everything is drawn. Coordinates   do not change unless device is turned on and moving. they are parsed from json everytime then put to polyline options and then drawn as polyline. 
Let me explain more what I want to do. Device has alot of functions. When function 1 is turned on. Device sends coordinates to json and when function 1 is turn off then it's not. because of divice moving while function 1 is turn off. polyline goes through whole map to the next point that is parsed when function 1 is turned on again. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: It makes sense. But your code logic apparently does not take into account the time the device spent moving while function 1 is turn off. You should have a way to detect that and adapt your code accordingly, right?